# Tensorflow GPU Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_11.dll not found

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

[When I try to run a tensoflow script for CUDA I get this Error: Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_11.dll not found
I looked into the bin folder of CUDA toolkit and I have a file named: cusolver64_11.dll
What can I do to fix it?

[image: 1]

Comment: I would guess that you have multiple CUDA runtimes installed and Tensorflow is finding one which is not the one you are looking at.  It appears that the Tensorflow build you have is looking for CUDA 11.2 and is finding CUDA 11.0 from somewhere. You are going to have to do some searching on your system to see what you can find and where you can find it and then configure Tensorflow and or system paths to allow it to search and find the right version

Comment: Could you please confirm Tensorflow version?  Recommended configuration fro CUDA 11 .0 and cuDNN 8.0 is tensorflow_gpu-2.4.0 . All the tested configurations are mentioned here .                                      https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows?hl=en#gpu